# jQuery selectable not working on canvas element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added a canvas element to an image and i want to add selectable to this canvas element as i want to draw a box around selected area:
    `<canvas class="marker" id="someID" style="width: 123px; height: 43px; top: 323px; left: 43.8594px; display: block;"></canvas>`

```
$("#someID").selectable();
```

I have multiple canvas elements in my code which are added dynamically wenever user selects an area on a image.
Please point me what is wrong with what i am doing?

Comment: Are you talking about a [jQuery UI Selectable](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/)?

Comment: Have you tried to surround it with a div ?

Comment: @AuxTaco Yes Its jQuery UI Selectable.

Comment: @PhilMaGeo when i tried to add selectable to the surrounded div , the page became unresponsive.....The viewer is by a third party....and also there are other events happening on the image like-mouse up,mouse move,mouse down

Comment: Can't you provide a working example ?

Comment: Can't you draw a border using canvas ?